# How to embed Flash content in my web page

Tags: html, flash

I need display Flash content in my web page. I am developing my web site in [**WAMP**](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and my PHP version is 2.5

```
<tr>
    <td height="31" align="center" valign="middle"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="260" height="23">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="movie" value="player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=song.mp3&amp;showstop=1&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showvolume=1" />
        <p>School Anthem</p>
    </object></td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately it is not displaying SWF file (Flash Player). Only displaying the `School Anthem` word. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: need some help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use the `<embed>` tag (but I never needed flashvars, so may not work for you).

According to this [**Adobe article**](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) your `<object>` code should look something like :

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="260" height="23" id="myFlashMovie" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name=FlashVars value="mp3=song.mp3&amp;showstop=1&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showvolume=1" />

    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="260" height="23">
        <param name="movie" value="player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
        <param name=FlashVars value="mp3=song.mp3&amp;showstop=1&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showvolume=1" />
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
    </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

If still not working then try a new html page with this `<embed>`code below  : 
 
(Put `.html` file and `swf` file together in same place or folder. Does it show anything?).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed src="player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="800" height="600">

</body>
</html>
```